# Deduce one dimension of 2D array at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, template-meta-programming

I have the following function:

```
template <int size>
double** writeArray(double input[size][2]) {

    double** Points = new double*[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        Points[i] = new double[2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        Points[i][0] = input[i][0];
        Points[i][1] = input[i][1];
    }

    return Points;
}
```

which writes from a `double[size][2]` array into a dynamically allocated `double **` pointer.

Is there any way to deduce the `size` automatically, so that I could use it like that:

```
double** Points = writeArray(Test1);
```

instead of:

```
double** Points = writeArray<2>(Test1);
```

Comment: Why not std::`vector`? etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! You can actually deduce *both* dimensions at compile-time. The idea is to write a template function that takes as its argument an array *by reference*. This prevents C++ from decaying the array type to a pointer type, which causes it to lose the array size. Here's an example:

```
template <typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
    void howBigAmI(T (&array)[M][N]) {
    std::cout << "You are " << M << " x " << N << " in size." << std::endl;
}
```

You should be able to adapt this to fit your needs if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass array by reference like:

```
template <int size>
double** writeArray(const double (&input)[size][2])
```